# Set UILabel which displays HTML inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uilabel

I'm trying to display a long HMTL content in a `UILabel` and I want it to **fit** the width correctly (like responsive HTML).

In Android it autorefits correctly and I'm doing it in iOS right now.

What I've done is a `UIScrollView` with that `UILabel` inside called `htmlLabel`. The `UILabel` is sticked to the top, left and right, and I let a bottom space from the `UIScrollView`:

[image]

and this is my code:

```
//html
[self.myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 20000)];
NSString * htmlString = item[@"content"];

NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

_htmlLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

but I can get only the first line:

[image]

what am I doing wrong??

Thank you in advance.

Regards.

Rafael.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the height of text that your label will need at your specified width. For example:

```
  CGFloat width = _htmlLabel.frame.size.width;
  CGRect rec = [htmlString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT)
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                        attributes:@{label.font}
                                           context:nil];
```

Set your _htmlLabel height to:

```
 rec.size.height;
```

You will also need to set your label's 'UILineBreakMode' to word wrap and set your label to multi line:

```
_htmlLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
_htmlLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```